# Why is there the use of を with 行ける

Tags: particle-を, transitivity

I came across this bit of dialog in a game

> 「深海」に行きたいっぱ！だから船**を**行けるようにしてほしいっぱ！

I know it, more or less, says:

> We want to go to the deep sea! Because of that, we want you to make sure that the boat can go!

But I don't understand why the を particle is being used in the second sentence. I would have expected で in this case, because the boat is how everyone would get to the deep sea (i.e. via boat). Why is the を particle being used here and what is the second sentence actually conveying?

Context:
A group of people want to go to a deep sea area, but they need the local craftsman to reenforce the boat so its actually possible.

Comment: You should parse the sentence like this: (船を)(行けるように)してほしいっぱ. を belongs to する not 行ける

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence literally means "We want to make the boat be able to go."

So the boat is the object the protagonist wants to act upon, that's why you need を and not で. It's not that they want to go by boat, they want to do something to the boat to make it work.

Comment: 'literally means' -- It's いけるようにしてほしい, not いけるようにしたい, so it's literally 'We want you(or somebody) to make the boat...' rather than 'We want to make the boat...', no?